# How to display validation errors on same dialog?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, hmvc

I am using codeigniter HMVC. I'm trying to create a sign up form that opens when sign up button is clicked. However, validation errors for the sign-up form appears on the parent page where the login form is located the dialog also closes after submitting data. What I want to do is to display the errors on the sign-up form dialog.

vw_login.php

```
<button  id="show-sign-up-dialog">Sign Up</button>       
<dialog  id="sign-up-dialog" >    
<button  id="close"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>

<?php echo form_open('user/sign_up', 'id = "reg_form" class="form-horizontal" role="form"');  ?>
 <!-- REGISTER USERNAME --> 
 <div class="form-group">
 <div class="col-12">
 <label for="name"></label>

 <?php
   $regi_username_attrib = array(
                'name' =>'register_username', 
                'class'=>'form-control mdl-input-login',
                'rows' =>'4',
                'placeholder'=>'Username'
                );
   echo form_error('register_username');
  echo form_input($regi_username_attrib, set_value('register_username', ''));  
  ?>

 </div>
 </div>
//Script to submit sign up form
    <script>
$(document).on("click", "#btn_sign_up", function ()
{
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url('user/sign_up');?>",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
            var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                if(obj!==null)
                {                             
                   $('#error_msg').html(obj['error_message']);                  
                }
                }});

});    


</script>
//Script to open sign up form 
<script>
   var dialog_AddEntry = document.querySelector('#sign-up-dialog');
   var showDialogButton_AddEntry = document.querySelector('#show-sign-up-dialog');
   if (! dialog_AddEntry.showModal) {
      dialogPolyfill.registerDialog(dialog_AddEntry);
    }
       showDialogButton_AddEntry.addEventListener('click', function() {
       dialog_AddEntry.showModal();
});
      dialog_AddEntry.querySelector('#close').addEventListener('click', function() {
      dialog_AddEntry.close();
});

</script>
```

Controller
    class User extends My_Controller {

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('vw_login');        
}

public function login()
{
    //|is_unique[tbl_user.user_username]
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) // If username and password is invalid
    {
        $this->load->view('vw_login');
    }
    else
    {

    } 

}
public function sign_up()
{
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('register_username', 'Username', 'trim|required');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) // If username and password is invalid
    {
        $this->load->view('vw_login');
        $data = array('error_message' => form_error('register_username'));
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
    else
    {

    }

}
```

}

Comment: what do you mean by parent page aren't you opening the signup form inside modal dialog ,one thing more i cant see the modal dialog trigger inside the on click events ajax call , you are parsing response and checking if valid object and throwing error where are you triggering the modal dialog to open

Comment: Sorry about that I didn't know how to refer to it. What I meant by parent page is the page which is already loaded before the modal appears by button click.

Comment: make sure there not any forms with the same names

Answer (score 0):

Add the following

```
<span id="error_msg"></span>
```

after

```
<label for="name"></label>
```

Comment: Try deleting  $this->load->view('vw_login'); from sign_up function

Comment: It displayed the validation error on another blank page

Comment: It means ajax form submit is not working, so remove <?php echo form_open('user/sign_up', 'id = "reg_form" class="form-horizontal" role="form"');  ?> and add <form> </form> instead of that